# Merge conflict with Visual Studio

Tags: json, git, git-merge-conflict

Currently my team is working on same .json file, one colleague is inserting a code just on the same line which I also inserted the code (e.g.)

My Colleague added:

line30: "it": "Nuovo Progetto"

I added:

line30: "es": "Nuevo Proyecto"

[image]
Visual Studio is taking the line29 also as a change, but this is not true because nobody make any change on this line. By trying to resolve the merge conflict and clicking on "Take Incoming" and "Take Current" line 29 is added on the bottom window:

[image]
How can I say to VStudio, that I want to keep the content of the line 30 from both (Incoming and current) sides? I want to avoid that the string "jp": "新規プロジェクト", appears twice.
[image]

Comment: I like smartgit client, which to my subjective feelings handled conflicts better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the merge result manually to remove lines 30 and 32 once you are sure they are not required.

See point 4 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#resolve-merge-conflicts-1).

Comment: This is easy to do when you have a small json-file. But with enterprise json files this is monastic work and hard to maintain. I'm having the same issue. On top of this, VS Code automatically replaces my spaces with tabs, causing the diff tool to think all lines are unique while they really aren't...